# Google's In-App Billing on Kindle and Nook device

Tags: android, in-app-billing, kindle, nook

Can some one confirm if Google's In-App Billing works on Kindle Fire and Nook devices or do we need to specifically use Amazon's In-App billing for the same?

Comment: i'm not sure but ... does it help you? [Getting Started With Android In-App Billing](http://www.coronalabs.com/corona-tutorials/getting-started-with-android-in-app-billing/)

Answer (score 1):

Google in-app purchase will not work on Kindle device as Google IAP requires Google Play app to be present on the device. For amazon you have to use their own in-app framework. See [Amazon In-app](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/in-app-purchasing.html)

For Nook, I'm not sure, you have to check Nook Developer guide line

Answer (score 0):

Legal issues aside, it depends on the Google Play Store (Android Market) app and associated infrastructure, so *Google* IAB won't work on any devices that lack those components. This most probably includes the Kindle Fire and Nook.